# Sci-fi movie from 80s-00s about a killer alien roaming a dark city

Tags: story-identification, movie

I vaguely remember a movie about an alien/monster roaming a dark/grim city. 
It could hibernate/burrow or drill underground, or used underground city infrastructure to move. It murdered different people, and might have resembled a trilobite? There was a fight scene when it emerged from garbage at landfill or just emerged from underground? Main character used a jeep, and there was also a woman supporting character?.Main character found a person killed in a brutal way or drilled in the head, like the alien harvested something. I thought the movie might be Split Second(1992) but i don't think it's a perfect match.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Where did you see this movie?  What language was it in?  Check out the other [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) in case they help you recall any more details you can [edit] into your question.

Answer (score 7):

Could it be "Mimic"? The creature is a giant cockroach thing that lives underground in subway tunnels and sewers. It can pull its wings over itself in a way to somewhat resemble a man in a trenchcoat on a dark subway platform.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be Tremors? Came out in 1990 so similar age. The monster is worm-like, burrows underground and kills multiple characters.

The lead ('Valentine') is played by Kevin Bacon, with Finn Carter as the geologist Rhonda Lebeck. Valentine and his friend Earl use a truck to get around. It was based in a rural town though, not a city.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hiAIvcWJ_yM)

Comment: Definitely not tremors series. Im still thinking its Split Second, and i have to rewatch it to be sure.

Comment: The graboids of *Tremors* and its sequels swallow people in one piece and doesn't resemble a trilobite at all.